# How to pronounce acronyms and initialisms with apostrophes?

Tags: pronunciation, possessives, acronyms, initialisms

Simple question:

How do you pronounce acronyms when they're used with apostrophe to express possession? For example:

> In the **NIH's** high-risk, high-reward programmes, “if an idea isn't developing the way it was expected to, awardees have the flexibility to pursue a more promising avenue of research”.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think typically you would follow the rules of pronunciation given the last letter of the acronym. So as mgb says, in your example it would be "En Aye Aitch ez". Some other examples:

> The US's: "The You Ess ez"
>
> The USA's: "The You Ess Ayz"
>
> The UK's: "The You Kayz"
>
> The CBC's: "The Cee Bee Ceez"

If the acronym is one that you read like a word, such as NASA, then you would follow the rules for words.

> NASA's: "Nassaz"

And so forth.

Comment: Excellent answer. Some pronunciations are very weird, don't you think? Particularly, US's, NIH's. On the contrary, UK's and CBC's sound good.

Comment: Agreed - it's that UK and CBC end in vowels (when you pronounce them). US's and NIH's require a whole extra syllable!

Comment: I wouldn't say it's any worse than the possesive case of names ending in 's', for example: Dickens's.

Comment: How about the classics? It's _Augustus's reign_ /ə'ɡəstəsəz ren/, but _Aristophanes' play_ /ɛrəs'tafəniz ple/.

Comment: @JohnLawler - that's just about worth another question, don't you think? Why Augustus's but Aristophanes'? Or is it simply a matter of personal taste?

Answer (score 4):

i would pronounce it "N I H -es"  ie "en hi aitch ez"